# How to save multiple inputs in a List to send to controller

Tags: c#, html, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form with a textbox, and when the user writes in a textbox, a new one appears. When he send the submit button, I want the value of every textbox to be sent to the controller, as a List or whatever object which will let me iterate it.

This is my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Escaneado</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Codigo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10" id="listaCodigos">
                <input type="text" id="Code0" class="form-control" autofocus />
                <!-- New inputs well be added here-->

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The code of the script which dynamically adds the inputs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var id = 1;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#listaCodigos').on('input', function () {
                $('<input type=\"text\" id=\"Code' + id + '\" class=\"form-control\"/>').appendTo("#listaCodigos");
                document.getElementById("Code" + id).focus();
                id++;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And the controller method:

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult NewGroupScan(List<String> listaCodigos)
        {
            //Method Logic
            return View();
        }
```

As it is right now, the List arrives null

Comment: Input fields without a name won't be sent to the server. Also, to post a list, use the same name for each input field and an index between square brackets (so, `listaCodigos[0]` and so on).

Comment: Input field with name attribute will be sent to the server to send a list simply use names in a array fashion like `name="Code[0]" , name="Code[1]", name="Code[2]"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, this is how the problem is solved:
The input

```
<input type="text" name="codesList[0]" id="Code0" class="form-control" autofocus />
```

The Script to insert the inputs:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var id = 1;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#listaCodigos').on('input', function () {
                $('<input type=\"text\" name=\"codesList[' + id + ']\" id=\"Code' + id + '\" class=\"form-control\"/>').appendTo("#listaCodigos");
                document.getElementById("Code" + id).focus();
                id++;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And how to get the List in the Controller:

```
public ActionResult NewGroupScan(List<String> codesList){...}
```